# Is it a way to make Qt signal with realization?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

When I declare in ,my class signal

```
signal: void someSignal();
```

there is no way that someSignal will have realization? If I try to write something like

```
void someClass::someSignal()
{//something here
}
```

I receive linkage error. So it is implemented somewhere, as far as I understand it is done by moc-compiler. So is it some way for me to write realization of the signal?

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the signals provide a prototype for a function in your class.
when you connect the signal to a slot, the call of `emit someSignal()` will call the slot connected to it.
so there is no need to define what your signal should do, cause the connected slot will do this.

soo long zai

Answer (score 4):

QT documentation says:

> Signals are automatically generated by the moc and **must not** be
>   implemented in the .cpp file

Therefore, there is no way to have implementation of signals. In fact, you need only call signals.
If you want to use signal as common function, just declare and implement new function :)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to do that, you only have to declare you signal and emit it using

```
 emit someSignal(pram1,pram2);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, but remember that the slot must have the same parameters as the signal and and not return( void ) ie:

emit someSignal( int pram1, int pram2 )   ------ signal

void someSignal( int pram1, int pram2 )   ------ slot

greetings